# Scrapy tumblr scraper not saving images

Tags: python, image, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl Tumblr for images. The scraper seems to be able to scrape the urls of the images but not download them.

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'tumblr'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tumblr.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tumblr.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\Users\123\Desktop'
```

items.py

```
import scrapy


class TumblrItem(scrapy.Item):

   image_urls = scrapy.Field()
   images = scrapy.Field()
```

tumblr_spider

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tumblr.items import TumblrItem

class TumblrSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tumblr'
    allowed_domains = ['tumblr.com']
    start_urls = ['http://free-indie-games.tumblr.com/archive']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/post']), 'parse_imgur')]

    def parse_imgur(self, response):
        image = TumblrItem()

        rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]
        return image
```

Log (It's long, so I'll put bits of it here)

```
2015-10-17 17:43:59 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://free-indie-   games.tumblr.com/post/63142153501>
    {'image_urls':     [u'http:http://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c4d1dcedfcd_128.png'],
     'images': []}
2015-10-17 17:44:00 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-10-17 17:44:00 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.ConnectError': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 8356,
 'downloader/request_count': 29,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 29,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 295766,
 'downloader/response_count': 26,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 26,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 17, 16, 44, 0, 951000),
 'item_scraped_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 55,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 26,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 26,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 26,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 26,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 26,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 17, 16, 43, 58, 83000)}
2015-10-17 17:44:00 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

To me it seems that it scrapes the urls but dont download the image. Nothing shows up in the computer at least.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extracted image url looks incorrect -

> http:http://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c4d1dcedfcd_128.png

`2015-10-17 17:43:59 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://free-indie-   games.tumblr.com/post/63142153501>
    {'image_urls':[u'http:http://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_0c4d1dcedfcd_128.png'],
     'images': []}`

To keep things safe, try using [urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) for generating proper urls instead of doing a string operation :

```
 rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
 image['image_urls'] = [urljoin(response.url, rel[0])]
```

Comment: It does indeed look wrong with the two 'http's. urljoin however gives me an error: "NameError: global name 'urljoin' is not defined"

I thought it was a predefined variable?

Comment: Nvm, forgot the import. Now it kind of works. Just not scraping the right stuff.

Comment: I think my xpath is wrong, I'm scraping stuff like the avatar and a few icons but not the images in the posts.

Comment: @user2514200 : You need to import urljoin from urlparse library  - "from urlparse import urljoin"